# How can i view this html property in angular cli app?

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml

I want to view this:

```
&lt;p&gt;In a transistor power amplifiers&lt;/p&gt;
```

I have used `<div [innerHTML]='question.en.value'></div>` but it only displays:

```
<p>In a transistor  power amplifiers</p>
```

not

```
In a transistor power amplifiers
```

what am i doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Such problems are usually caused by misguided server/API designs. Although of course you can unescape it yourself, your shouldn't have to. The server should be fixed to return HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unescape your string, so that "<" gets replaced with "<". For example lodash can help you with this, just run:

```
npm i --save lodash
```

import unescape:

```
import { unescape } from 'lodash';
```

and use it to unescape your string:

```
value = unescape('&lt;p&gt;In a transistor power amplifiers&lt;/p&gt;');
```